# How to use choices in Google App Engine NDB Model

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I want to create a model of ndb.Model of Google App Engine in Python. One of the fields is a choice, there will be 4 options (0 to 3) and each option will have a string representing it. How do I define this field in the model? I want the strings to show in the form, but the number to be saved to the database (I don't want to save the option names to the database). How do I use choices? Is it possible to use a dictionary or list of tuples? I also want to define constants for the numbers 0 to 3. How do I implement it in Google App Engine? We are using Django templates and I want to do something similar to what we do in Django.

By the way, is it possible to use Google App Engine NDB with Django? It's a new application and we can use Django if it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just keep your strings in a constant with keys. Something like this will work:

```
choices = {0: 'Foo', 1: 'Bar', ...}

class Model(ndb.Model):
  choice = ndb.IntegerProperty(choices=choices.keys())

# you can easily generate such form using wtforms..
class ModelForm(wtforms.Form):
  choice = wtforms.fields.SelectField(
    choices=[(k, v) for k, v in choices.iteritems()])
```